# Use extra fields in ubercart add to cart form

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, ubercart, drupal-hooks

I am trying to implement hotel booking functionality in a **Drupal 7.26** website. Customers will choose hotels from a listing page and then they will select rooms within the hotel.

I decided to use **UberCart 3** for my booking mechanism.

First I implemented 'Hotel' as a Ubercart product. But a hotel is connected to rooms, each type of room has a different price. Using product attributes, I designed room type as an attribute, with each room type having a different price. So far so good, but **I could not select multiple instances of any single product attribute, so I abandoned using Product Attributes.**

Then I decided on this different approach. I decided to keep the room type information inside the hotel product type, using field groups.

[image]

Here's how it looks in the add content page:

[image]

Using some view templating, I managed this look in my booking page. This look is exactly how my clients want (apart from the css anyway). I am getting to book multiple instances of a room.

[image]

However, when I click on any 'Add to cart' button, Drupal does not detect that which room type was selected. I modified the rendered markup of the Add to cart form (using tpl files), and added a hidden field called roomtype for each add to cart button. So for the first button, roomtype = 'double', and for the second button, roomtype = 'single'.

My idea was to

- use **hook_uc_add_to_cart**,
- then process this roomtype value,  and
- then compute the price of that roomtype,
- then update the price of the cart item,
- and then redirect to cart page.

But hook_uc_add_to_cart provides only quantity, node id and a data variable. **None of these gives me the value of the roomtype hidden field.**

How do I use my hidden fields in my uc_add_to_cart hook?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
http://drupaldeveloper.in/codelet/drupal-add-product-field-cart-ubercart

This code has similar solution.

Regards.